# Running test in kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have setup a kotlin multiplatform project and want to run junit tests.

But a

```
gradle clean build
```

just delivers:

```
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.0-rc'
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version "$kotlin_version"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
                implementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.2'
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2"
                implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2"
                implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my test (lies in src/jvmTest/kotlin):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class JvmTest {
    @Test
    fun testX() {
        println("Hello World")
        println("Hello World")
        println("Hello World")
        println("Hello World")
        println("Hello World")
    }
}
```

I would expect the outputs of Hello World, but as you can see, there is no output.

What do I have to change, that the test is executed? Or is it executed and the output is just not shown? What can I do, to see the output of the test?

I've also tried kotlin version 1.3.72. Same result.

EDIT: I changed the test to

```
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class JvmTest {
    @Test
    fun testX() {
        assertTrue(false)
    }
}
```

Same result, build runs succeful, no test is executed. There are no files in build/reports/tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
tasks.jvmTest{
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

in the build.gradle fixes the problem.

build.gradle now looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.0-rc'
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version "$kotlin_version"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib')
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                dependsOn commonTest
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
                implementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.2'
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
                runtimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2"
                implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2"
                implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2"
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.jvmTest{
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: If you are using Kotlin DSL for your Gradle configuration, this is how you do it: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1105#issuecomment-573740028

Answer (score 0):

Look in `[project]/build/reports/tests` and look for the various `index.html` files.

Also, to verify that a test is run, it might be easier to fail the test rather than print a statement. Something like the following.

```kotlin
@Test
fun testX() {
    assertTrue(false)
}
```

I assume all of your tests are in the jvm source as they import junit. I'd also try one in the commonTest source to make sure that's all working as expected.

Comment: i changed as you said. The test is build, but not executed. There are no report files.

Comment: I had tests in the jvm and common section. None is executed. So I reduced it to jvm tests, to check them first, if they are executed. Afterwards I would have gone back to find out, if I can run common tests.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing changes. Actually it still seems that the test is not executed. Otherwise tests results must be shown.

Comment: Aren’t the tests supposed to be in `src/main/test`?